# Who is Sheba talking to Solomon or David through the Rukh?

Tags: magi

I've just finished reading Magi manga chapter 234. My question: is Sheba talking to Solomon or David through the Rukh, after Solomon Sealed away Il Illah? I don't want an answer that is based on rumors ahead of the story, I'm just asking if this is Solomon or David.

[image: a page from the manga]

I mean she is sure he is Solomon (after all that's how she Addresses him) but my guess is that this is David who intentionally confuses Sheba that she is talking to her husband. Please answer with facts till chapter 234, if it's something leaked which will be revealed later I'd rather not know it by now. Thanks!